# Show fixed 100 m x 100 m grid on lowest zoom level

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap

I am using leaflet with openstreetmap to create a fixed grid on top of the world map that consists of 100m x 100m tiles. Basically, I am creating a turn-based game, where a player should be able to click on a certain tile, which then reveals a context menu. The server is going to know that the player has opened the tile for a certain place.

I tried the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>GridLayer Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <style>
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        html,
        body,
        #map {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

    <script>
        var map = new L.Map('map', { center: [10, 0], zoom: 2 });

        var tiles = new L.GridLayer();
        tiles.createTile = function (coords) {
            var tile = L.DomUtil.create('canvas', 'leaflet-tile');
            var ctx = tile.getContext('2d');
            var size = this.getTileSize()
            tile.width = size.x
            tile.height = size.y

            // calculate projection coordinates of top left tile pixel
            var nwPoint = coords.scaleBy(size)

            // calculate geographic coordinates of top left tile pixel
            var nw = map.unproject(nwPoint, coords.z)

            ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, size.x, 50);
            ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
            ctx.fillText('x: ' + coords.x + ', y: ' + coords.y + ', zoom: ' + coords.z, 20, 20);
            ctx.fillText('lat: ' + nw.lat + ', lon: ' + nw.lng, 20, 40);
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
            ctx.lineTo(size.x - 1, 0);
            ctx.lineTo(size.x - 1, size.y - 1);
            ctx.lineTo(0, size.y - 1);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.stroke();
            return tile;
        }

        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.osm.org">OpenStreetMap</a>',
            minNativeZoom: 1,
            maxNativeZoom: 1,
        }).addTo(map)

        tiles.addTo(map)
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see the grid changed when I zoom in or out, even though I used `minNativeZoom`. However, I would like to have the grid fixed and 100m x 100m wide.

I also tried to only return `tile` when `zoomLevel = 18`. This does not work.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want the user to be able to zoom in and out of the map, but the tiles should be come bigger or smaller, while still representing the same 100mx100m area?

Comment: @Steve Zoom should be possible for the user and the tiles should become bigger or smaller based on the 100mx100m area. Alternatively, it could be also good that the grid is only shown on a certain zoom level.

Comment: @Carol.Kar I believe my solution meets all the requirements set in your two answers. Let me know if you feel anything is missing! If it works for you, I'd appreciate that bounty. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can draw a grid with the following `createTile` implementation:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>GridLayer Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <style>
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        html,
        body,
        #map {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

<script>

    const numTilesX = 2 ** 17
    const numTilesY = 2 ** 17

    class TileNumber {
        constructor(x, y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
        equals(other) {
            return this.x === other.x && this.y === other.y;
        }
    }

    let coloredTiles = [
        new TileNumber(70435, 45249),
        new TileNumber(70434, 45248),
        new TileNumber(70441, 45245)
    ]

    function latLngToTileNumber(latLng) {
        const lngDegrees = latLng.lng;
        const latRadians = latLng.lat * (Math.PI/180);
        return new L.Point(
            numTilesX * ((lngDegrees + 180) / 360),
            numTilesY * (1 - Math.log(Math.tan(latRadians) + 1 / Math.cos(latRadians)) / Math.PI) / 2
        );
    }

    const map = new L.Map('map', {center: [48.5748229, 13.4609744], zoom: 16, maxZoom: 19});

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.osm.org">OpenStreetMap</a>', maxZoom: 19
    }).addTo(map)

    const tiles = new L.GridLayer({minZoom: 12});
    tiles.createTile = function (coords) {
        const tile = L.DomUtil.create('canvas', 'leaflet-tile');
        const ctx = tile.getContext('2d');
        const size = this.getTileSize();
        tile.width = size.x
        tile.height = size.y

        // calculate projection coordinates of top left tile pixel
        const nwPoint = coords.scaleBy(size);
        // calculate geographic coordinates of top left tile pixel
        const nw = map.unproject(nwPoint, coords.z);
        // calculate fraction tile number at top left point
        const nwTile = latLngToTileNumber(nw, Math.floor)

        // calculate projection coordinates of bottom right tile pixel
        const sePoint = new L.Point(nwPoint.x + size.x - 1, nwPoint.y + size.y - 1)
        // calculate geographic coordinates of bottom right tile pixel
        const se = map.unproject(sePoint, coords.z);
        // calculate fractional tile number at bottom right point
        const seTile = latLngToTileNumber(se, Math.ceil)

        const minTileX = nwTile.x
        const maxTileX = seTile.x
        const minTileY = nwTile.y
        const maxTileY = seTile.y

        for (let x = Math.ceil(minTileX) - 1; x <= Math.floor(maxTileX) + 1; x++) {
            for (let y = Math.ceil(minTileY) - 1; y <= Math.floor(maxTileY) + 1; y++) {

                let tile = new TileNumber(x, y)

                const xMinPixel = Math.round(size.x * (x - minTileX) / (maxTileX - minTileX));
                const xMaxPixel = Math.round(size.x * (x + 1 - minTileX) / (maxTileX - minTileX));
                const yMinPixel = Math.round(size.y * (y - minTileY) / (maxTileY - minTileY));
                const yMaxPixel = Math.round(size.y * (y + 1 - minTileY) / (maxTileY - minTileY));

                // fill the rectangle with a color
                ctx.fillStyle = coloredTiles.some(t => t.equals(tile))
                    ? 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3)'
                    : 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)';
                ctx.fillRect(xMinPixel, yMinPixel, xMaxPixel - xMinPixel, yMaxPixel - yMinPixel);

                if (coords.z >= 16) {
                    // draw the white rectangle and text at the top of the cell
                    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
                    ctx.fillRect(xMinPixel, yMinPixel, xMaxPixel - xMinPixel, 28);
                    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
                    ctx.font = "15px Arial"
                    ctx.fillText(tile.x + "," + tile.y, xMinPixel + 10, yMinPixel + 20, xMaxPixel - xMinPixel);
                }

                if (coords.z >= 13) {
                    // draw a border
                    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
                    ctx.strokeRect(xMinPixel, yMinPixel, xMaxPixel - xMinPixel, yMaxPixel - yMinPixel);
                }

            }
        }

        return tile;

    }

    tiles.addTo(map);

    map.on('click', e => {

        const fractionalTileNumber = latLngToTileNumber(e.latlng);
        const tileNumber = new TileNumber(Math.floor(fractionalTileNumber.x), Math.floor(fractionalTileNumber.y));

        console.log("Tile " + tileNumber.x + " " + tileNumber.y  + " clicked");

        if (coloredTiles.some(t => t.equals(tileNumber))) {
            coloredTiles = coloredTiles.filter(t => !t.equals(tileNumber));
        } else {
            coloredTiles.push(tileNumber);
        }

        tiles.redraw();

    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Some caveats:

- Because the earth isn't flat, it's not really possible to cleanly cover it with a grid of rectangles. So I did the closest thing to it by drawing grid boundaries along latitude and longitude lines. As a result, the tiles will get larger (cover more square meters) towards the equator and smaller towards the poles.
- Each grid cell has an unique `TileNumber` (x and y coordinate, starting at 0,0 in the northwestern corner).
- To demonstrate clicking on the map, I'm writing the `TileNumber` of the to the log and toggle the tile's colored/uncolored state. Of course, this could be replaced with any other functionality imaginable, including communication with a server.

As this snippet includes the ability to color the grid cells based on their `TileNumber` (stored in an array), I've provided this as an answer to your [question about coloring grid tiles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71240826/1391631) as well.