# Color certain grid tiles based on coordinates

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I would like to color certain grid tiles based on their coordinates.

I created the following grid:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Color Tiles</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.css" />

    <style>
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        html,
        body,
        #map {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="map"></div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

    <!-- Make sure you put this AFtER leaflet.js, when using with leaflet 
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-geosearch@3.0.0/dist/geosearch.umd.js"></script>
    -->

    <script>
        var map = new L.Map('map', { center: [10, 0], zoom: 2 });

        let zoomLevel = map.getZoom()
        console.log("zoomLevel " + zoomLevel)

        // if(zoomLevel === 1) {
            var tiles = new L.GridLayer();
            tiles.createTile = function (coords) {
                var tile = L.DomUtil.create('canvas', 'leaflet-tile');
                var ctx = tile.getContext('2d');
                var size = this.getTileSize()
                // console.log("size: " + size.toString())
                tile.width = size.x
                tile.height = size.y

                // calculate projection coordinates of top left tile pixel
                var nwPoint = coords.scaleBy(size)

                // calculate geographic coordinates of top left tile pixel
                var nw = map.unproject(nwPoint, coords.z)

                ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, size.x, 50);
                ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
                ctx.fillText('x: ' + coords.x + ', y: ' + coords.y + ', zoom: ' + coords.z, 20, 20);
                ctx.fillText('lat: ' + nw.lat + ', lon: ' + nw.lng, 20, 40);
                ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
                ctx.lineTo(size.x - 1, 0);
                ctx.lineTo(size.x - 1, size.y - 1);
                ctx.lineTo(0, size.y - 1);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.stroke();
                return tile;
            }

            L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.osm.org">OpenStreetMap</a>',
            }).addTo(map)

            tiles.addTo(map)
    
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I would like to have the following:

[image]

I tried to style it directly via css, which seems to work. However, I would like to style it based on the provided coordinates.

Any suggestion how to do this?

Comment: Conditionally fill a rectangle spanning the full canvas with semiopaque blue?

Comment: @IvanSanchez Thx for your question. I would like to fill specific tiles with blue based on the coordinates. I was thinking to pass the coordinates as an array and then certain tiles are filled with blue.

Comment: Do you mean that, given a list of _points_ (each point represented by a [lat, lng]), any tile that contains (or touches?) any of these points, should be colored in blue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What type of Coordinates?

Looking at your other question about using maps for a turn-based game, there may be some ambiguity over what "coordinates" means. You may mean **geographic** coordinates (i.e. latitude and longitude) which represents a **point** on a map or globe. On the other hand, you may mean coordinates to a **tile** (e.g. the 4th row, 5th column, at zoom level 3 of a certain tileset) which would represent an area on a map or globe. I'll go over approaches for both cases.

#### Geographic Coordinates

Leaflet has built in ways to detect whether specific [`LatLng` coordinates](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlng) are within bounds, by using the [`LatLngBounds`.`contains` method](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds-contains).

First you can define an array of key coordinates and then create leaflet [`LatLng` objects](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlng) from them:

```
var keyCoordinates = [
  [ -5.9, -123.9 ],
  [ -12, -28.5 ]
];
var leafletKeyCoordinates = keyCoordinates.map(function (c) {
  return new L.LatLng(c[0], c[1]);
});
```

To determine the boundaries of a specific tile, you can calculate the southwest corner of the tile. From this part:

```
// calculate projection coordinates of top left tile pixel
var nwPoint = coords.scaleBy(size)
// calculate geographic coordinates of top left tile pixel
var nw = map.unproject(nwPoint, coords.z);
```

Add:

```
// calculate projection coordinates of bottom right tile pixel
var sePoint = nwPoint.add(size);
// calculate geographic coordinates of bottom right tile pixel
var se = map.unproject(sePoint, coords.z);
var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(nw, se);
```

From there, you can use the bounds for each tile to determine whether it should be shaded. You can do this by either drawing on the canvas or applying a class to the tile. For an example using the canvas, at the bottom of `createTile`, add:

```
// if it contains any coordinates, it should be filled
var shouldShade = leafletKeyCoordinates.some(function (a) {
  return bounds.contains(a);
});
if (shouldShade) {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 240, 0.3)';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, size.x, size.y);
}
```

All Together:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Color Tiles</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.css" />

    <style>
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        html,
        body,
        #map {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="map"></div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

    <!-- Make sure you put this AFtER leaflet.js, when using with leaflet 
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-geosearch@3.0.0/dist/geosearch.umd.js"></script>
    -->

    <script>
        var map = new L.Map('map', { center: [10, 0], zoom: 2 });

        let zoomLevel = map.getZoom()
        console.log("zoomLevel " + zoomLevel)

        var keyCoordinates = [
          [ -5.9, -123.9 ],
          [ -12, -28.5 ]
        ];
        var leafletKeyCoordinates = keyCoordinates.map(function (c) {
          return new L.LatLng(c[0], c[1]);
        });

        // if(zoomLevel === 1) {
            var tiles = new L.GridLayer();
            tiles.createTile = function (coords) {
                var tile = L.DomUtil.create('canvas', 'leaflet-tile');
                var ctx = tile.getContext('2d');
                var size = this.getTileSize()
                // console.log("size: " + size.toString())
                tile.width = size.x
                tile.height = size.y

                // calculate projection coordinates of top left tile pixel
                var nwPoint = coords.scaleBy(size)

                // calculate geographic coordinates of top left tile pixel
                var nw = map.unproject(nwPoint, coords.z)
                // calculate projection coordinates of bottom right tile pixel
                var sePoint = nwPoint.add(size);
                // calculate geographic coordinates of bottom right tile pixel
                var se = map.unproject(sePoint, coords.z);
                var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(nw, se);

                ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, size.x, 50);
                ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
                ctx.fillText('x: ' + coords.x + ', y: ' + coords.y + ', zoom: ' + coords.z, 20, 20);
                ctx.fillText('lat: ' + nw.lat + ', lon: ' + nw.lng, 20, 40);
                ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
                ctx.lineTo(size.x - 1, 0);
                ctx.lineTo(size.x - 1, size.y - 1);
                ctx.lineTo(0, size.y - 1);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.stroke();

                // if it contains any coordinates, it should be filled
                var shouldShade = leafletKeyCoordinates.some(function (a) {
                  return bounds.contains(a);
                });
                if (shouldShade) {
                  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 240, 0.3)';
                  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, size.x, size.y);
                }
return tile;
            }

            L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.osm.org">OpenStreetMap</a>',
            }).addTo(map)

            tiles.addTo(map)
    
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

#### Tile Coordinates

In the case of tiles, you can directly look at `coords.x` and `coords.y` for the column and row, and `coords.z` for the zoom level. The tricky part of this is that if there are varying levels of zoom, your user may be at a different zoom than the tiles you've identified.

```
var tileCoordinates = [
  [0, 3, 3], // x, y, and zoom of tile
  [28, 6, 5]
];
```

To translate between zoom levels, each zoom level doubles the tile coordinates (for example, the tile (0, 2) at zoom level 4 is represented by the tiles (0, 4), (0, 5), (1, 4), (1, 5) at zoom level 5)). We can use `Math.pow(2, targetZoom - coords.z)` or `Math.pow(2, coords.z - targetZoom)` to determine the factor to multiply by.

```
var { x, y, z } = coords;
var shouldShade = tileCoordinates.some(function (c) {
  let [ tx, ty, tz] = c, multiple, sx, sy;
  if (z < tz) {
     // map is zoomed out from the target
     // you may just want to `return false;` here
     multiple = Math.pow(2, tz - z);
     sx = Math.floor(tx / multiple);
     sy = Math.floor(ty / multiple);
     return sx === x && sy === y; 
  } else if (z > tz) {
     // map is zoomed in from the target
     multiple = Math.pow(2, z - tz);
     sx = Math.floor(x / multiple);
     sy = Math.floor(y / multiple);
     return sx === tx && sy === ty; 
  }
  return tx === x && ty === y;
});
```

All together:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Color Tiles</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.css" />

    <style>
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        html,
        body,
        #map {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="map"></div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

    <!-- Make sure you put this AFtER leaflet.js, when using with leaflet 
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-geosearch@3.0.0/dist/geosearch.umd.js"></script>
    -->

    <script>
        var map = new L.Map('map', { center: [10, 0], zoom: 2 });

        let zoomLevel = map.getZoom()
        console.log("zoomLevel " + zoomLevel)

        var tileCoordinates = [
          [0, 3, 3],
          [28, 6, 5]
        ];

        // if(zoomLevel === 1) {
            var tiles = new L.GridLayer();
            tiles.createTile = function (coords) {
                var tile = L.DomUtil.create('canvas', 'leaflet-tile');
                var ctx = tile.getContext('2d');
                var size = this.getTileSize()
                // console.log("size: " + size.toString())
                tile.width = size.x
                tile.height = size.y

                // calculate projection coordinates of top left tile pixel
                var nwPoint = coords.scaleBy(size)

                // calculate geographic coordinates of top left tile pixel
                var nw = map.unproject(nwPoint, coords.z)
                // calculate projection coordinates of bottom right tile pixel
                var sePoint = nwPoint.add(size);
                // calculate geographic coordinates of bottom right tile pixel
                var se = map.unproject(sePoint, coords.z);
                var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(nw, se);

                ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, size.x, 50);
                ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
                ctx.fillText('x: ' + coords.x + ', y: ' + coords.y + ', zoom: ' + coords.z, 20, 20);
                ctx.fillText('lat: ' + nw.lat + ', lon: ' + nw.lng, 20, 40);
                ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
                ctx.lineTo(size.x - 1, 0);
                ctx.lineTo(size.x - 1, size.y - 1);
                ctx.lineTo(0, size.y - 1);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.stroke();

                var { x, y, z } = coords;
                var shouldShade = tileCoordinates.some(function (c) {
                  let [ tx, ty, tz] = c, multiple, sx, sy;
                  if (z < tz) {
                    // map is zoomed out from the target
                    // you may just want to `return false;` here
                    multiple = Math.pow(2, tz - z);
                    sx = Math.floor(tx / multiple);
                    sy = Math.floor(ty / multiple);
                    return sx === x && sy === y; 
                  } else if (z > tz) {
                    // map is zoomed in from the target
                    multiple = Math.pow(2, z - tz);
                    sx = Math.floor(x / multiple);
                    sy = Math.floor(y / multiple);
                    return sx === tx && sy === ty; 
                  }
                  return tx === x && ty === y;
                });

                if (shouldShade) {
                  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 240, 0.3)';
                  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, size.x, size.y);
                }
return tile;
            }

            L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.osm.org">OpenStreetMap</a>',
            }).addTo(map)

            tiles.addTo(map)
    
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can use [`array.some()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of abusing `reduce`

Comment: Good point, it's much cleaner! Updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use the internal `_tileCoordsToBounds` function from Leaflet to get the bounds of the tile and check if the latlng is in it.

I extended `L.GridLayer` because it is much cleaner. The important function is `_isLatLngInCoords`:

```
L.ColoredTiles = L.GridLayer.extend({
    colorLatLngs: [],
    initialize (latlngs, options) {
        L.Util.setOptions(this, options);
        if(latlngs && L.Util.isArray(latlngs) && latlngs.length > 0) {
            this.colorLatLngs = latlngs;
        }

        if(this.options.debug) {
            this._showDebugLatLngs();
        }
    },
    createTile (coords) {
        var tile = L.DomUtil.create('canvas', 'leaflet-tile');
        var ctx = tile.getContext('2d');
        var size = this.getTileSize()
        // console.log("size: " + size.toString())
        tile.width = size.x
        tile.height = size.y

        // calculate projection coordinates of top left tile pixel
        var nwPoint = coords.scaleBy(size)

        // calculate geographic coordinates of top left tile pixel
        var nw = map.unproject(nwPoint, coords.z)

        ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, size.x, 50);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
        ctx.fillText('x: ' + coords.x + ', y: ' + coords.y + ', zoom: ' + coords.z, 20, 20);
        ctx.fillText('lat: ' + nw.lat + ', lon: ' + nw.lng, 20, 40);
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(size.x - 1, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(size.x - 1, size.y - 1);
        ctx.lineTo(0, size.y - 1);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();

        if (this._isLatLngInCoords(coords)) {
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 240, 0.3)';
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, size.x, size.y);
        }

        return tile;
    },
    _isLatLngInCoords(coords) {
        var tileBounds = this._tileCoordsToBounds(coords);
        return this.colorLatLngs && this.colorLatLngs.some(function (a) {
            return tileBounds.contains(a);
        });
    },
    setColorLatLngs(latlngs){
        this.colorLatLngs = latlngs;
        this.redraw();

        if(this.options.debug) {
            this._showDebugLatLngs();
        }
    },
    _showDebugLatLngs(){
        this.fg = this.fg || L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
        this.fg.clearLayers();
        this.colorLatLngs && this.colorLatLngs.forEach((latlng)=>{
            L.marker(latlng).addTo(this.fg);
        })
    }
});
```

And then add it to the map:

```
var colorLatLngs = [
    L.latLng(0,0),
    L.latLng(2,2),
];
        
var tiles = new L.ColoredTiles(colorLatLngs).addTo(map)
```

I also added the function `setColorLatLngs(array)` to change the latlngs and update the colored tiles.

```
tiles.setColorLatLngs([L.latLng(3,3)]);
```

And for the debug purpose I added the option `debug: true` to set markers on each latlng. So it is clearly visible which tiles should be colored.

```
var tiles = new L.ColoredTiles(colorLatLngs, {debug: true}).addTo(map)
```

#### Demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Color Tiles</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.css" />

<style>
    body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    html,
    body,
    #map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="map"></div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

<!-- Make sure you put this AFtER leaflet.js, when using with leaflet 
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-geosearch@3.0.0/dist/geosearch.umd.js"></script>
-->

<script>
var map = new L.Map('map', { center: [10, 0], zoom: 2 });

let zoomLevel = map.getZoom()
console.log("zoomLevel " + zoomLevel)

L.ColoredTiles = L.GridLayer.extend({
    colorLatLngs: [],
    initialize (latlngs, options) {
        L.Util.setOptions(this, options);
        if(latlngs && L.Util.isArray(latlngs) && latlngs.length > 0) {
            this.colorLatLngs = latlngs;
        }

        if(this.options.debug) {
            this._showDebugLatLngs();
        }
    },
    createTile (coords) {
        var tile = L.DomUtil.create('canvas', 'leaflet-tile');
        var ctx = tile.getContext('2d');
        var size = this.getTileSize()
        // console.log("size: " + size.toString())
        tile.width = size.x
        tile.height = size.y

        // calculate projection coordinates of top left tile pixel
        var nwPoint = coords.scaleBy(size)

        // calculate geographic coordinates of top left tile pixel
        var nw = map.unproject(nwPoint, coords.z)

        ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, size.x, 50);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
        ctx.fillText('x: ' + coords.x + ', y: ' + coords.y + ', zoom: ' + coords.z, 20, 20);
        ctx.fillText('lat: ' + nw.lat + ', lon: ' + nw.lng, 20, 40);
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(size.x - 1, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(size.x - 1, size.y - 1);
        ctx.lineTo(0, size.y - 1);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();

        if (this._isLatLngInCoords(coords)) {
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 240, 0.3)';
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, size.x, size.y);
        }

        return tile;
    },
    _isLatLngInCoords(coords) {
        var tileBounds = this._tileCoordsToBounds(coords);
        return this.colorLatLngs && this.colorLatLngs.some(function (a) {
            return tileBounds.contains(a);
        });
    },
    setColorLatLngs(latlngs){
        this.colorLatLngs = latlngs;
        this.redraw();

        if(this.options.debug) {
            this._showDebugLatLngs();
        }
    },
    _showDebugLatLngs(){
        this.fg = this.fg || L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
        this.fg.clearLayers();
        this.colorLatLngs && this.colorLatLngs.forEach((latlng)=>{
            L.marker(latlng).addTo(this.fg);
        })
    }
});

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.osm.org">OpenStreetMap</a>',
}).addTo(map)

var colorLatLngs = [
    L.latLng(0,0),
    L.latLng(2,2),
];
var tiles = new L.ColoredTiles(colorLatLngs, {debug: true}).addTo(map)
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking about something this way :

Added :

```
if (nw.lat > 10) {
   ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)";
   ctx.fillRect(0, 50, size.x, size.y - 50);
}
```

Up to you to use any condition that allow you to localize the tiles.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Color Tiles</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.css" />

    <style>
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        html,
        body,
        #map {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="map"></div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

    <!-- Make sure you put this AFtER leaflet.js, when using with leaflet 
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-geosearch@3.0.0/dist/geosearch.umd.js"></script>
    -->

    <script>
        var map = new L.Map('map', { center: [10, 0], zoom: 2 });

        let zoomLevel = map.getZoom()
        console.log("zoomLevel " + zoomLevel)

        // if(zoomLevel === 1) {
            var tiles = new L.GridLayer();
            tiles.createTile = function (coords) {
                var tile = L.DomUtil.create('canvas', 'leaflet-tile');
                var ctx = tile.getContext('2d');
                var size = this.getTileSize()
                // console.log("size: " + size.toString())
                tile.width = size.x
                tile.height = size.y

                // calculate projection coordinates of top left tile pixel
                var nwPoint = coords.scaleBy(size)

                // calculate geographic coordinates of top left tile pixel
                var nw = map.unproject(nwPoint, coords.z)

                ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, size.x, 50);
                if (nw.lat > 10) {
                    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)";
                    ctx.fillRect(0, 50, size.x, size.y - 50);
                }
                ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
                ctx.fillText('x: ' + coords.x + ', y: ' + coords.y + ', zoom: ' + coords.z, 20, 20);
                ctx.fillText('lat: ' + nw.lat + ', lon: ' + nw.lng, 20, 40);
                ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
                ctx.lineTo(size.x - 1, 0);
                ctx.lineTo(size.x - 1, size.y - 1);
                ctx.lineTo(0, size.y - 1);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.stroke();
                return tile;
            }

            L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.osm.org">OpenStreetMap</a>',
            }).addTo(map)

            tiles.addTo(map)
    
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This snippet simultaneously solves the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71231865/1391631). It decides which tiles to color based on an array of `TileNumber` objects:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>GridLayer Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <style>
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        html,
        body,
        #map {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

<script>

    const numTilesX = 2 ** 17
    const numTilesY = 2 ** 17

    class TileNumber {
        constructor(x, y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
        equals(other) {
            return this.x === other.x && this.y === other.y;
        }
    }

    let coloredTiles = [
        new TileNumber(70435, 45249),
        new TileNumber(70434, 45248),
        new TileNumber(70441, 45245)
    ]

    function latLngToTileNumber(latLng) {
        const lngDegrees = latLng.lng;
        const latRadians = latLng.lat * (Math.PI/180);
        return new L.Point(
            numTilesX * ((lngDegrees + 180) / 360),
            numTilesY * (1 - Math.log(Math.tan(latRadians) + 1 / Math.cos(latRadians)) / Math.PI) / 2
        );
    }

    const map = new L.Map('map', {center: [48.5748229, 13.4609744], zoom: 16, maxZoom: 19});

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.osm.org">OpenStreetMap</a>', maxZoom: 19
    }).addTo(map)

    const tiles = new L.GridLayer({minZoom: 12});
    tiles.createTile = function (coords) {
        const tile = L.DomUtil.create('canvas', 'leaflet-tile');
        const ctx = tile.getContext('2d');
        const size = this.getTileSize();
        tile.width = size.x
        tile.height = size.y

        // calculate projection coordinates of top left tile pixel
        const nwPoint = coords.scaleBy(size);
        // calculate geographic coordinates of top left tile pixel
        const nw = map.unproject(nwPoint, coords.z);
        // calculate fraction tile number at top left point
        const nwTile = latLngToTileNumber(nw, Math.floor)

        // calculate projection coordinates of bottom right tile pixel
        const sePoint = new L.Point(nwPoint.x + size.x - 1, nwPoint.y + size.y - 1)
        // calculate geographic coordinates of bottom right tile pixel
        const se = map.unproject(sePoint, coords.z);
        // calculate fractional tile number at bottom right point
        const seTile = latLngToTileNumber(se, Math.ceil)

        const minTileX = nwTile.x
        const maxTileX = seTile.x
        const minTileY = nwTile.y
        const maxTileY = seTile.y

        for (let x = Math.ceil(minTileX) - 1; x <= Math.floor(maxTileX) + 1; x++) {
            for (let y = Math.ceil(minTileY) - 1; y <= Math.floor(maxTileY) + 1; y++) {

                let tile = new TileNumber(x, y)

                const xMinPixel = Math.round(size.x * (x - minTileX) / (maxTileX - minTileX));
                const xMaxPixel = Math.round(size.x * (x + 1 - minTileX) / (maxTileX - minTileX));
                const yMinPixel = Math.round(size.y * (y - minTileY) / (maxTileY - minTileY));
                const yMaxPixel = Math.round(size.y * (y + 1 - minTileY) / (maxTileY - minTileY));

                // fill the rectangle with a color
                ctx.fillStyle = coloredTiles.some(t => t.equals(tile))
                    ? 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3)'
                    : 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)';
                ctx.fillRect(xMinPixel, yMinPixel, xMaxPixel - xMinPixel, yMaxPixel - yMinPixel);

                if (coords.z >= 16) {
                    // draw the white rectangle and text at the top of the cell
                    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
                    ctx.fillRect(xMinPixel, yMinPixel, xMaxPixel - xMinPixel, 28);
                    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
                    ctx.font = "15px Arial"
                    ctx.fillText(tile.x + "," + tile.y, xMinPixel + 10, yMinPixel + 20, xMaxPixel - xMinPixel);
                }

                if (coords.z >= 13) {
                    // draw a border
                    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
                    ctx.strokeRect(xMinPixel, yMinPixel, xMaxPixel - xMinPixel, yMaxPixel - yMinPixel);
                }

            }
        }

        return tile;

    }

    tiles.addTo(map);

    map.on('click', e => {

        const fractionalTileNumber = latLngToTileNumber(e.latlng);
        const tileNumber = new TileNumber(Math.floor(fractionalTileNumber.x), Math.floor(fractionalTileNumber.y));

        console.log("Tile " + tileNumber.x + " " + tileNumber.y  + " clicked");

        if (coloredTiles.some(t => t.equals(tileNumber))) {
            coloredTiles = coloredTiles.filter(t => !t.equals(tileNumber));
        } else {
            coloredTiles.push(tileNumber);
        }

        tiles.redraw();

    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```