# Grid on map with Leaflet

Tags: css, angular, typescript, dictionary, leaflet

I am new to programming and I am interested in learning more about the Leaflet tools and I am interested in knowing how to better configure the labels in the L.gridLayer, and if it is possible to leave the labels in a certain range so that they do not appear in all the tiles. I'm currently working with Angular 12.1.4.

I appreciate any guidance or support

[image]

```html
 var grid = L.gridLayer({
      attribution: 'Grid Layer',
      tileSize: L.point(300, 300),
      opacity: 0.5,
      updateWhenZooming:false,
      
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! By "labels", are you referring to the Lat/Lng text that appears in top left corners of tiles in your screenshot? IIRC, this is not the default Leaflet Grid Layer behaviour. Can you share the exact code that is used in your screenshot?

Comment: Look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71293532/8283938 instead of coloring the tiles you can simply add the text or remove it